# Textarea wont allow me to write into it [React]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, textarea

I'm making a web app with react and in one of my functions I fetch some data from the backend and then I show it to the user by changing the value of the textarea. The problem is that I want the textarea not to be edited when the user presses a button to fetch the data from the backend but then if I click the textarea I want it to erease the data fetched and allow the user to write into itself.

This is how the code looks like in the component that contains the textarea:

```
<div id="text-div" onClick={this.onWrite}>
    <textarea id="text" rows={13} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea></div>
<Button onClick={this.handleRead}>Read</Button>

//functions within the code
onWrite() {
    // do stuff
    document.getElementById("text").setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
}

async handleRead() {
    // fetches data and saves it into this.state.value
    document.getElementById("text").setAttribute("contentEditable", false);
}
```

I've also tried using `readOnly` but it doesn't work either, when I call `handleRead()` it doesnt let the user write and shows the data (as expected) but when i call `onWrite()` (it would set readOnly property to false) it does not let the user write. So I cant revert what `handleRead()` did.

I would really appreciate some suggestions because I'm kind of a noob in React and this is my first project, sorry if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

`contenteditable` is an attribute added to non-editable fields like `div` to make them editable

You want to use `readonly` or `disabled`

I converted your example to vanilla to make it usable here

```js
function onWrite() {
  // do stuff
  document.getElementById("text").removeAttribute("readonly");
}

async function handleRead() {
  document.getElementById("text").value = 'test'
  document.getElementById("text").setAttribute("readonly", true)
}
```

```html
<div id="text-div" onclick="onWrite()">
  <textarea id="text" rows="13"></textarea>
</div>
<button onclick="handleRead()">Read</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work! At least for me, maybe it has something to do with states in React or something. I tried before with disabled but I had the same problem, it stayed disabled forever.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you have already assigned some value to your input field.
So use `defaultValue` instead of `value`
So try writing your code like this

```html
<div id="text-div" onClick={this.onWrite}>
    <textarea id="text" rows={13} defaultValue={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    </textarea>
</div>

<Button onClick={this.handleRead}>Read</Button>
```

This should solve your problem.